# Tmux copy mode appears to have empty history

Tags: tmux

I just moved to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from 18.04 (fresh install instead of upgrade), and installed tmux via `apt install tmux`. Everything seems to work fine except when I enter copy mode, it appears to think my history is empty. I get `[0/0]` in the top right and can't scroll at all (and I can't use enter to escape, I have to use esc). I've removed my `~/.tmux.conf`, and I've tried uninstaling and reinstalling and restarting my computer. Nothing seems to help. Any ideas what's wrong and what I can do to fix it?

**SOLVED** I still get the `[0/0]` but I figured out why I can't scroll. Apparently there's a vi mode that for my old ubuntu install and work macbook was/is on by default. I just had to add to my `~/.tmux.conf` the line `setw -g mode-keys vi` as described [here](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/vi-mode-in-tmux/).